# Show message box if value not found in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a Excel VBA search box.  How can I put a message box when records not found on the list?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Me.TextBox1.Value = UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value)
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim P As Long
Me.ListBox1.Clear

For i = 2 To sh.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To Len(sh.Cells(i, 6))
P = Me.TextBox1.TextLength

If LCase(Mid(sh.Cells(i, 6), x, P)) = Me.TextBox1 And Me.TextBox1 <> "" Then

With Me.ListBox1
.AddItem sh.Cells(i, 1)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = sh.Cells(i, 2)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = sh.Cells(i, 3)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = sh.Cells(i, 4)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = sh.Cells(i, 5)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = sh.Cells(i, 6)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = sh.Cells(i, 7)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 7) = sh.Cells(i, 8)

End With
End If
Next x
Next i

r = Sheet1.Columns("A").ColumnWidth * 7
ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "70;60;80;230;230;100;60;" & r & ";"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Me.TextBox1.Value = UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value)
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim P As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    
    
    For i = 2 To sh.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 1 To Len(sh.Cells(i, 6))
        P = Me.TextBox1.TextLength
        
        If LCase(Mid(sh.Cells(i, 6), x, P)) = Me.TextBox1 And Me.TextBox1 <> "" Then
        
            n = n + 1 '<~~ count items
        
            With Me.ListBox1
                .AddItem sh.Cells(i, 1)
                .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = sh.Cells(i, 2)
                .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = sh.Cells(i, 3)
                .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = sh.Cells(i, 4)
                .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = sh.Cells(i, 5)
                .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = sh.Cells(i, 6)
                .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = sh.Cells(i, 7)
                .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 7) = sh.Cells(i, 8)
            
            End With
        End If
        Next x
    Next i
    If n Then
        MsgBox n & " Items were selected", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "value not found", vbInformation
    End If
    
    r = Sheet1.Columns("A").ColumnWidth * 7
    ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "70;60;80;230;230;100;60;" & r & ";"
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your reply sir. but the code its not working sir.  i uploaded the workbook on mediafire. my code is in "userform1" .hope you can help me thank you so much  http://www.mediafire.com/file/8musv403fuiaq7x/1-DATABASE.xls/file

Comment: @Makoy,  change  line  `n=n+1`  to below the  if statement.

Comment: can you download my woorkbook and edit the code. cause still not working on me. Thank you so much. https://www.mediafire.com/file/8musv403fuiaq7x/1-DATABASE.xls/file

Comment: Thank you so much sir. it work's perfectly!!!..  God Bless you sir.

Comment: @Makoy, If it works for you, please accept the answer.